# How to add authentication to the k8s service

Tags: authentication, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an application with type NodePort.
Can I add authentication without rewriting deployments?
Maybe there is a simple yaml ingress example to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[NGINX Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) has a lot of authentication ways, for example the simplest [Basic Authentication](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/) that uses a secret that contains a file generated with htpasswd.

To create secret:

```
$ htpasswd -c auth foo
New password: <bar>
New password:
Re-type new password:
Adding password for user foo
$ kubectl create secret generic basic-auth --from-file=auth
secret "basic-auth" created
$ kubectl get secret basic-auth -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  auth: Zm9vOiRhcHIxJE9GRzNYeWJwJGNrTDBGSERBa29YWUlsSDkuY3lzVDAK
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: basic-auth
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
```

To use in Ingress rule:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-with-auth
  annotations:
    # type of authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    # name of the secret that contains the user/password definitions
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    # message to display with an appropriate context why the authentication is required
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - foo'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Examples also available in [ingress-nginx auth examples page](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/auth)